If $f(x) = Ae^{x} + Be^{-x}$ and $f(1) = 0$, then $f(x) = C\sinh(x - 1)$
I need to find a function $f(x)$ of the form  $$ f(x) = Ae^{x} + Be^{-x} \;\; A,B \in \mathbb{R} $$ with $f(1) = 0$
The professor immediately concluded that $$ f(x) = C \sinh(1-x) \;\;\; C \in \mathbb{R} $$ and it looks correct but I wonder
a) How do you get to this solution?
b) How do you know this is the only independent solution?

Hint: any linear combination of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ can be written with hyperbolic sines and cosines. Further, use the given condition to make the conclusion.

If $f(1) = 0$, one gets that
\begin{align*}
f(1) = Ae^{1} + Be^{-1} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow Ae^{2} + B = 0 \Longleftrightarrow B = - Ae^{2}
\end{align*}
Consequently, one has that
\begin{align*}
f(x) & = Ae^{x} - Ae^{2}e^{-x}\\\\
& = A(e^{x} - e^{2 - x})\\\\
& = Ae(e^{x - 1} - e^{1 - x})\\\\
& = 2Ae\left(\frac{e^{x - 1} - e^{1 - x}}{2}\right)\\\\
& = C\sinh(x - 1)
\end{align*}
where $C := 2Ae$.
Hopefully this helps!
